# How to calculate the probability for this multinomial logit model?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, logit

In multinomial logit models, the probability of the observed choice ranked 1st among all option is given by this formula:

```
p(choice = j) = exp(x_j*b)/(\sum(x_i*b))
```

I am wondering if there is any compact formula to calculate the probability of any alternative j is ranked 5th, or 6th in this model.

Comment: "the probability of the observed choice ranked 1st among all option" vs "p(choice = j)". Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula does not compute the probability of being "1st ranked" but simply the probability of being "selected" - So eventually you could compute this probability for each option and then use this information to rank order the options in terms of "desirability" (i.e., likelihood of being selected). To compute the probability of being 1st/2nd/etc. ranked, you would need a raking information (not only observed choices).